# react-admin need to refresh the page to get the aside to load the ReferenceManyField properly

Tags: react-admin

I have a react-admin Show Component that uses aside to display information of similar situation related to the current record displayed

```
function R3Show() {
  return (
    <Show
      title={<PageTitle />}
      aside={<RelatedR3s />}
    >
      <SimpleShowLayout
        sx={{
          border: '2px solid HotPink',
        }}
      >
        <RepairStatus label={`resources.r3s.customFields.statusR3s`} />
        <RepairDuration />
        <TextField source='remark' />

        [some other fields]

      </SimpleShowLayout>
     </Show>
  );
```

and the RelatedR3s is

```
export function RelatedR3s({ source = 'id', pagination = <Pagination /> }) {
  const translate = useTranslate();

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        marginLeft: '1rem',
      }}
    >
      <Divider
        sx={{
          marginBottom: '1rem',
        }}
      >
        <Chip label={translate('resources.r3s.customFields.relatedR3s')} />
      </Divider>
      <ReferenceManyField
        reference='r3s'
        target='machine_id'
        source={source}
        sort={{ field: 'r3Date', order: 'DESC' }}
        perPage={7}
        allowEmpty={true}
        pagination={pagination}
      >
        <Datagrid
          bulkActionButtons={false}
          rowClick='show'
        >
          <RepairStatus
            label={translate('resources.r3s.customFields.statusR3s')}
          />
          <RepairDuration
            label={translate('resources.r3s.customFields.repairDuration')}
          />
          <TextField source='r3Number' />
          <DateField
            source='r3Date'
            locales='zh-CN'
          />
          <ReferenceField
            source='applicant_id'
            reference='profiles'
            link='show'
          >
            <ChipField source='name' />
          </ReferenceField>
        </Datagrid>
      </ReferenceManyField>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

so the problem is that sometimes the aside shows "no result found", but if I reload the page then the related records will show up.

the console gives the error

> query.js:358
>
> ```
>    Error: target and id are required
> at __assign.onSuccess
> ```

So I believe it has to be a problem for the ReferenceManyField cannot find a target /source,

if I move the component within the SimpleShowLayout (so it would be after all the fields for example) then there is no problem, so does that means that aside doesnt have access to the current record?

is there a way to put my component on the side instead of below ?

thanks a lot for anyone who can help
N.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping my component inside  solved the issue

`aside={<WithRecord render={() => <RelatedR3s />} />}`